# Tracking outbond links with Google Analytics Pageviews or Event?

Tags: redirect, google-analytics, outbound

I used so far GA pageviews of oubound links by sending the links to a page that redirects.

The link looks like  www.mysite/redirect.php?vars=$vars1&vars=$vars1&vars=$vars1&**target_url=url**

The link url contains some variables that gives me some information that I can filter with GA pageviews.

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.location = 'target_url'</script>
```

Now I read that this method may not be reliable. Is that true or does the redirect method works fine?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I do not know if  GA counts pageviews reliable or not by using window.location method?

Comment: Obviously GA won't track you when you click on that link, you have to enter an event to send to GA when the user clicks on the link (onclick...), es: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en

Comment: I think you missunderstood the point. I did not showed the complete script. The question was if redirect of outbound links create reliable pageview results thus can be an alternative of event tracking.

Comment: If you talk about reliable data in the destination URL, the one where you are taken after the redirect, you should check if the original source is kept with the redirect.